# Adjust Volume In Google Native-Client

Tags: c++, c, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I've wrote media/stream player using google chrome native-client (nacl). The problem is that Pepper audio API does not have function to control audio level. Is there any way to adjust volume with nacl while playback?

[EDIT]

I've fixed this problem by manually changing the volume in the audio sample buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The web page containing the plugin could use the chrome.audio API to do this. Unfortunately, this will only work in Dev channel Chrome.

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/audio